# How to specify domain?

Tags: complex

I wrote

x $\in$ Reals; y$\in$ Reals;

z = x + I y;

Re[z]

gave the output

-Im[y] + Re[x]

as if the first line did not exist

How can I specify that x and y are reals?

Comment: Don't guess/assume, read the documentation. `Element` doesn't do what you assume it does. It can be used in the `Assumptions` option, but it does not add a permanent assumption to the current session. You can use `ComplexExpand`, or you can use `Refine` with its second argument or `Assumptions` option.

Comment: @Szabolcs You are right. I am quite overwhelmed by the documentation, tbh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[x, y, z]
$Assumptions = x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals
z = x + I y
Refine@Re[z]
```

(* x *)

or

```
Assuming[x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals, 
 Refine[Re[z = x + I y]]]
```

(* x *)

Read the documentation for [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) and `Refine`.

Answer (score 1):

```
z = x + I y;
Simplify[Re[z], Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals && y∈ Reals]
```

Or

```
z = x + I y;
z // Re // ComplexExpand
z//ReIm//ComplexExpand
```

Comment: The first gives Re[x], the second works fine, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
FullSimplify[ReIm[x + I y], {x, y} ∈ Reals]
```

> {x, y}